# Syntax error on token "start" , identifier expected after this token

Tags: java, agents-jade

I've been trying to create an agent thanks to Jade on Java with this code:

```
import jade.core.ProfileImpl;
import jade.wrapper.AgentContainer;
import jade.wrapper.AgentController;

public class Agents {
    jade.core.Runtime rt= jade.core.Runtime.instance();
    ProfileImpl pMain= new ProfileImpl();
    AgentContainer mc = rt.createMainContainer(pMain);
    AgentController rma= mc.createNewAgent("rma", "jade.tools.rma.rma", null);
    rma.start();
}
```

I keep getting the error *"Syntax error on token "start" , identifier expected after this token"* and I cannot understand why.

Comment: You can't just randomly write any java code anywhere inside a class body. Put it in a method or better yet: Step back and start over with a basic java tutorial before you try to use more complicated Frameworks and APIs

Answer (score 0):

By not going into finding problems with your code, I suggest to use the code below to solve your error.

Initialization code for agent and adding to the container

```
package package.se.samplejade;
import jade.wrapper.AgentController;
import jade.wrapper.StaleProxyException;

public class LaunchAgents {
    private static final String AGENT_CLASS_STRING ="package.se.samplejade.SampleAgent";
    private static final String AGENTNAME_STRING = "sampleAgent";

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         LaunchAgents LaunchAgents = new LaunchAgents();
         LaunchAgents.initilizeAgent();

    }

    /**
     * Creates a new agent and adds it to the container
     * 
     * @param 
     * @return  true or false 
     */
    public boolean initilizeAgent() {

     AgentController agentcontroller = null;
     Object[] initObjects = new Object[2];
     initObjects[0] = new Object(); // add any object needed to initialize the agent
     initObjects[1] = new Object();
      try {
            agentcontroller = Container.getController().createNewAgent(AGENTNAME_STRING, AGENT_CLASS_STRING,
                    initObjects);
            agentcontroller.start();
            return true;
         } catch (StaleProxyException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
         }
      }

    }
```

The JADE container initialization

```
package.se.samplejade ;
import jade.core.Profile;
import jade.core.ProfileImpl;
import jade.wrapper.ContainerController;

public final class Container {

    // get a JADE runtime
    private static jade.core.Runtime runtime = jade.core.Runtime.instance();
    // Create a profile, where the launch arguments are stored
    private static Profile profile2 = new ProfileImpl();
    private static Profile profile = new ProfileImpl();
    // create the Main-container
    private static ContainerController mainContainer = null;
    private static ContainerController containerController = null;
        /**
         * Returns the path of the container to the JADE agents
        */
    public synchronized static ContainerController getController() {

        // create the Main-container
        if (mainContainer == null) {
            profile.setParameter(Profile.CONTAINER_NAME, "Container");
            profile.setParameter(Profile.GUI, "true");
            mainContainer = runtime.createMainContainer(profile2);
            containerController = runtime.createAgentContainer(profile);
        }

        return containerController;
    }

  }
```

The agents code

```
  package.se.samplejade;
  import jade.core.Agent;
  public class SampleAgent  extends Agent  {

     @Override
      protected void setup() {
          //Put your agent initialization code with the objects passed in the initialization 

       }

    }
```